# Paypal recurring payment not retrieving Transaction ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-sandbox

i m using paypal Standard as a payment gateway, i need to use recurring payment process for that. but i am not getting any Transaction ID in which paypal send response back to my site.. Is anybody having idea about this..? I am stuck on this task.

help would be very appreciate..
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem today as well. It seems that there are no transaction IDs involved with recurring payments but instead it uses another variable called profile ID. I tried subscribing and cancelling multiple times and it generated unique ID results so I'm pretty sure that is the unique identifier. I'm assuming this is done so that you don't a new transaction ID recurring period and that it always refers to the same subscription (profile) ID.

Comment: yes, actually i solve this prob already.but yes you are absolutely right. Thanx. +1..:)

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what this variable is you get back? I can't get anything back?